# "Cannot convert value of type" error in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I've got the following error:

[image]

with Xcode-beta 5 and Swift. In beta 4 it works fine. Anybody who can help me?

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
                (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The change from NSError to Error is *documented* in the beta 5 release notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the error. Look as the type of your `error` parameter. You've declared it as `NSError` but the error message is telling you that it should be declared as `Error`, not `NSError`.

So you code should be:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
                (response: URLResponse?, data: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```